# Custom checkboxes form Validation - Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1, validation, form-validation

I have 2 checkbox fields and only one of them have to be required (the first or the second)

**How can I show an error message only if the 2 checkboxes are not selected.**

It is possible to do that with prototype ? or have I to search a solution with jQuery ?

Edit:
[image]

The user have to choose one or many option(s) from "Checkbox group 1" or "Checkbox group 2", but not options from the 2 groups. Only one group have to be selected

Edit2: for info I'm using https://amasty.com/customer-attributes.html
and I want to to customise the generated form...

And here is the generated code of My form fields :

```
<fieldset id="amcustomerattr66" class="amcustomerattr">
<span class="field-row" id="checkbox_group1">
<label for="checkbox_group1">Checkbox group1</label><div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div class="amorderattr_img_checkbox" style="float: left; clear: none; padding-right: 4px;"><div><input type="checkbox" class="" name="billing[amcustomerattr][checkbox_group1][]" id="checkbox_group1___30" value="30">&nbsp;Option 1</div></div><div class="amorderattr_img_checkbox" style="float: left; clear: none; padding-right: 4px;"><div><input type="checkbox" class="" name="billing[amcustomerattr][checkbox_group1][]" id="checkbox_group1___31" value="31">&nbsp;Option 2</div></div><div class="amorderattr_img_checkbox" style="float: left; clear: none; padding-right: 4px;"><div><input type="checkbox" class="" name="billing[amcustomerattr][checkbox_group1][]" id="checkbox_group1___32" value="32">&nbsp;Option 3</div></div><input type="hidden" class="" name="amcustomerattr[checkbox_group1][]" id="checkbox_group1___0" value=""><div style="clear: both;"></div><div style="padding: 4px;"></div></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var checkbox_group1ElementControl = {
     selectAll: function() { 
         var sel = $("checkbox_group1");
         for(var i = 0; i < sel.options.length; i ++) { 
             sel.options[i].selected = true; 
         } 
         return false; 
     },
     deselectAll: function() {
         var sel = $("checkbox_group1");
         for(var i = 0; i < sel.options.length; i ++) { 
             sel.options[i].selected = false; 
         } 
         return false; 
     }
  }

</script><span class="field-row" id="checkbox_group2">
<label for="checkbox_group2">Checkbox group2</label><div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div class="amorderattr_img_checkbox" style="float: left; clear: none; padding-right: 4px;"><div><input type="checkbox" class="" name="billing[amcustomerattr][checkbox_group2][]" id="checkbox_group2___33" value="33">&nbsp;Option 4</div></div><div class="amorderattr_img_checkbox" style="float: left; clear: none; padding-right: 4px;"><div><input type="checkbox" class="" name="billing[amcustomerattr][checkbox_group2][]" id="checkbox_group2___34" value="34">&nbsp;Option 5</div></div><input type="hidden" class="" name="amcustomerattr[checkbox_group2][]" id="checkbox_group2___0" value=""><div style="clear: both;"></div><div style="padding: 4px;"></div></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var checkbox_group2ElementControl = {
     selectAll: function() { 
         var sel = $("checkbox_group2");
         for(var i = 0; i < sel.options.length; i ++) { 
             sel.options[i].selected = true; 
         } 
         return false; 
     },
     deselectAll: function() {
         var sel = $("checkbox_group2");
         for(var i = 0; i < sel.options.length; i ++) { 
             sel.options[i].selected = false; 
         } 
         return false; 
     }
  }

</script>







<script type="text/javascript">
   var fav_colorElementControl = {
     selectAll: function() { 
         var sel = $("fav_color");
         for(var i = 0; i < sel.options.length; i ++) { 
             sel.options[i].selected = true; 
         } 
         return false; 
     },
     deselectAll: function() {
         var sel = $("fav_color");
         for(var i = 0; i < sel.options.length; i ++) { 
             sel.options[i].selected = false; 
         } 
         return false; 
     }
  }

</script><span class="field-row" style="display: none;">
<label for="company_name">Name of the company</label><div style="clear: both;"></div>
<input id="company_name" name="billing[amcustomerattr][company_name]" value="" class=" input-text" type="text">
<div style="padding: 4px;"></div></span>
<span class="field-row" style="display: none;">
<label for="company_specialization">Company specialization</label><div style="clear: both;"></div>
<textarea id="company_specialization" name="billing[amcustomerattr][company_specialization]" class=" textarea" rows="2" cols="15"></textarea><div style="padding: 4px;"></div></span>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume you have the two checkboxes like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="my_checkbox[1]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="my_checkbox[2]" value="2" />
```

You can use **the default `validate-one-required-by-name` class to let the default prototype validation validate one required option:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="my_checkbox[1]" value="1" class="validate-one-required-by-name" />
<input type="checkbox" name="my_checkbox[2]" value="2" class="validate-one-required-by-name" />
```

Please note that the name of the input is important. The name must be arrays like in my example for the validation to work properly.

In your case you will have to add that class to the 5 inputs.

Also, **to be able to use the validation properly you need to add that small JS after your form:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var myCustomForm= new VarienForm('custom-form');
//]]>
</script>
```

Where `custom-form` is the id of your `<form>` element.

Comment: Thank you Raphael, the issue is always present, I have edited my question with an image and more description. I hope that it's better fo a solution now

Comment: @Bizboss please post the code that displays those checkboxes please

Comment: @ Raphael please see my last edit

Comment: @Bizboss I've edited my answer ;)

Comment: @ Raphael have you tested the edit solution ? I have tested it and it always doesn't works as expected.

Comment: @Bizboss I have tested that locally in Magento core but not with your script. That's definitely the right way of doing it, I suggest you debug the `validate-one-required-by-name` in the validation.js file to find out what your issue is

Comment: Thank you Raphael, bur that works only for one checkboxes group, and make no relation between the 2 checkbox groups.

Comment: @Bizboss what if you merge the two groups into one single group ?

Comment: @ Raphael: Yes, that's what I have done for the moment, but it was a little complicated to give each checkbox group a different Label and to show them correctly in the frontend... It would be better to have 2 different inputs, but seems not to be easy

Comment: @Bizboss yes it sounds tricky. You could declare your own validation javascript but that's quite some work if you're dealing with complex checkbox structures

Comment: @ Raphael: Thanks for your advices, I'll award the bounty for now and accept it as a useful one